# Specify recipients of an UIActivityViewController (Share Sheet)?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an array of contacts fetched from a contact list. I want to take these contacts and use them as recipients of my `UIActivityController`.

```
var contactLocations = [URL]() // this should be filled with the contact URLs 

let textToShare = "Hello, this is the link:"
var objectsToShare = [textToShare, url] as [Any]

objectsToShare.append(self.contactLocations)

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender.customView
self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can't specify recipients but just the data you want to share with UIActivityViewController. Or do you want to share to contact data?

Comment: Why not use MFMailComposeViewController directly instead?

Comment: When you use `UIActivityViewController`, the user has full control over what is selected and if they choose Mail, they control who to send the email to as well as the subject and message body.

Comment: Thanks @D.Mika – got it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ReinierMelian – great idea. I thought that was the "email sheet" because of its misleading name "MailCompose". Will totally check it out. Edit: I would like to use a share sheet (`UIActivityViewController`, not email sheet preferably).

Comment: Please note that you can _never_ completely control who the user sends an email to if you present a built-in email-construction view controller, because the user can change the To field. You can suggest, but you cannot force.

Comment: @D.Mika Feel free to use your comment as an answer. I must use an `UIActivityController` but, as you mentioned, it's not possible to set its recipients. I now know it's not possible – this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify recipients but just the data you want to share with UIActivityViewController.